# Using ROLLUP with COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running into an issue when using `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)` while using `ROLLUP`. Everything looks correct when I run the query without `ROLLUP`, but when I do, the rollup value is only for the distinct values from each GROUP BY, instead of the total sum. I realize that I could use a subquery to get the total; however, the main query is very large so I'm hoping to find another way to work around the issue. Any ideas?

Example of the query:
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1) FROM table GROUP BY column2 WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Can you please show the query you wrote, or a simpler example query that exposes the same behaviour?

Comment: So you want a roll up for the entire table (sum of all group level count(distinct coloumn_name)?

Comment: @Isildur That is correct

Comment: @Davidm113021 What version of MySQL are you using? Could you not add a window function `sum over()` to the select? Window functions are applied after the group by so you won't need a subquery

Comment: @Isildur I am using 5.7 which unfortunately does not support window functions

Comment: Too bad, I was about to suggest `UNION ALL` with a `WITH` clause, but MySQL 5.7 doesn't support this either.

Comment: I suppose in that MySQL version there is no other way than copying the whole code and use it twice, once for the distinct group counts and one for the sum of the distinct group counts.

Comment: @Isildur Thanks so much! I actually just used `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a,b))` and it seems to be doing just what I need

Comment: @Davidm113021 Glad that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hacky way to get around that using `concat` in the `select` itself. User [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) provided an edge case where [this doesn't work](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bSqkaBEkzzymJExStvo3ix/1). Use it **only if** your data doesn't exhibit that type of problem

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(column1, column2))
FROM table 
GROUP BY column2 WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: @Davidm113021 I updated my answer to include a word of caution for an edge case where this solution won't work exactly as expected. Unless you're certain about your data, I would use caution.

Comment: I removed my comment and code because I'm not sure what the requiremnt is exactly, but anyway a *hacky* way needs thorough testing.